# Error: Callback is not a function (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

When I execute my code I keep getting the error 'TypeError: callback is not a function'.
This is the relevant code:

```
exports.isVideo = function(tweetId, callback) {
  client.get('statuses/show/' + tweetId, function(err, tweet, res){
    if(tweet.extended_entities){
        if(tweet.extended_entities.media[0].type === 'video'){
            console.log('true');
            callback(true);
        } else {
            console.log('false');
            callback(false);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('false');
        callback(false);
    }
  });
}
```

This is in a different file (I required the first file at the top of this one, that's not the reason for the error):

```
ids.forEach(function(id){
    console.log(id.twitterId);
    twitterConverter.isVideo(id.twitterId, function(boolean){
        if(boolean){
            console.log('do something');
        } else {
            console.log('do nothing');
        }
    });
});
```

First of all, please don't just mark this as duplicate because there are other posts with similar titles. I looked through them, and the reason was usually that no callback function was passed, or too many parameters were passed, which isn't the case here.

I'm not that experienced with nodejs yet, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't find what's wrong with this code.

`client.get()` is from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) npm package. Maybe the error has something to do with that?

I would be very glad if you could help me out here.

Comment: Try logging `typeof callback` ? Might give you a hint. Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure you're not calling that function somewhere else without a callback?

Comment: typeof callback returns undefined. Which is weird, I really don't know why it doesn't return function.

Comment: Have you handle 'err' in callback of client.get() already?
maybe there're some errors and none of your 'callback' executes and  be treated  not as a callback function ?

Comment: I think you are not passing `function` but passing `function result` which is obviously not a function.  Try  extracting callback function outside and assign it to a variable and then pass that variable  without `()`.

Comment: Also, i think the `callback` is losing it's context inside `client.get `.

Answer (score 1):

The caller of the callback (which is the `client.get` method in this case) decides what arguments are passed to the callback. You need to declare your callback to match what `client.get` says that it will pass to the callback. You can name the arguments anything you want (the names you use do not matter), but they will get values in the order that `client.get` decides.

In this case, `client.get` calls the callback with the three arguments you have in your code as in `function(err, tweet, res)`.So your `callback` need to be something like this:

```
    callback(null,null,true);
```

Code is:

```
    exports.isVideo = function(tweetId, callback) {
    client.get('statuses/show/' + tweetId, function(err, tweet, res){
    if(tweet.extended_entities){
    if(tweet.extended_entities.media[0].type === 'video'){
        console.log('true');
        callback(null,null,true);

    } else {
        console.log('false');
        callback(null,null,false);

    }
    } else {
    console.log('false');
    callback(null,null,false);

     }
     });
     }
```